# Changing Password of a user in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, passwords

I'm making an intranet website in which there is a functionality of change password.

When the user enters the old and new password, it checks the old password with the current password and if both matches then it updates the new password in the database.

When i look at the database then the value in password column is changed but if I try to login with the new password then it doesn't happen but it logins with the old password.

Now If I stop the application and Build/Run again then it takes the updated password.

Why is it happening like this?

```
 public JsonResult ChangePwd(string OldPwd, string NewPwd)
     {
         string username = User.Identity.Name.ToUpper();
         USER_DET temp = objUser.getUserByName(username);
         if (temp.Password.ToString() == OldPwd.ToUpper())
         {


             temp.Password = NewPwd.ToUpper();
             objUser.Update(temp);
             var data2 = new[] {
      new { Text="True", Value="1" }//Password Changed

         };
             return Json(data2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
         else
         {
             var data2 = new[] {
               new { Text="False", Value="1" }//Password didnt match... no changes

                 };
             return Json(data2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
     }
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you post some more details including some code.

Comment: *if I try to login with the new password then it doesn't happen but it logins with the old password* Debug your login method, which credential it takes old one or updated one.

Comment: @Div .....Thanks buddy. You were right there were some issues in the Login Method.

Comment: @Sudhanshu, Hmm, glad that helped :)

Comment: Just FYI, you shouldn't really be storing plain text passwords. Hash them instead, and compare the hash.

Comment: @Wurd , yes you are right. I have included the encryption and decryption module.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I have managed to get it working. I was using a function in Membership provider class which was not getting the updated values from the database. So Instead of using that I created a separate function which is getting the updated values.